# LDAP query not working in custom web part

Tags: development, web-part, active-directory, custom, ldap

I have a custom web part which will pull Active directories custom attribute(logged in user). For testing purpose currently I am trying to get "mail" of currently logged in user. But it is not working. Here is my code

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rp.fs.asdf.org");
            DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry, "(sAMAccountName=myuserid1)", new string[] { "mail" });
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
            SearchResult result = mySearcher.FindOne();
            if (result != null)
            {
                mailID = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
            }
            entry.Close();
            entry.Dispose();
            mySearcher.Dispose();
```

The same code works perfectly in "Windows form". 
I have been fighting with this code. Please suggest some ideas. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I have to embed this in SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using .Net 3.5 `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;` you can query AD using below code

```
string userName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.UserName;
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain","DC=MyDomain,DC=com");
UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, userName);
```

Once you have that you can get Email using `oUserPrincipal.Email`

Comment: I tired this approach also but it didnot work. But when I give username and password it is working. Does it mean I have pass logged in user name and password for this? How can I get user password to pass?

Comment: Ideally this works when logged in user has correct permissions on AD. Can you confirm the logged in user has enough permission to query AD?

Comment: I am the logged in user and I am able to query it from "windows forms". It is not working only from web part.  I think I solved it. I have to use  "SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges", now it works.